# Command line parsing in shell script

Tags: bash, shell, getopts

I have a shell script where i am parsing command line argument. My arguments has path in it.
Example: `mycript.sh -c test -s global -n /mydir/test1 -d /orgdir/test35`
When I run the script and echo the arguments which contains path(special char "/"), it gives me empty path.

```
#/!bin/bash
...

while getopts c:hs:n:d opt
do
case "$opt" in
c) INST=$OPTARG;;
d) INST_DIR=$OPTARG;;
h) usage;;
s) METHOD=$OPTARG;;
n) MAINTENANCE_DIR=$OPTARG;;
\?) usage;;
esac
done

echo INST dir is [$INST_DIR]
echo MAINTENANCE dir is [$MAINTENANCE_DIR]
.......
```

Result of this echo is

```
INST dir is []
MAINTENANCE dir is []
```

Can someone tell what is incorrect here?

Comment: it's not a direct solution to your problem, but I'd advice you to have a look at [docopt](https://github.com/docopt/docopts) which is a portable (across languages) way to parse arguments.

Comment: `docopt` is still a 3rd-party solution, though. `getopts` is part of `bash`, and so is completely portable (given the assumption that `bash` is available, anyway).

Answer (score 2):

With your script, I have a different result:

```
INST dir is []
MAINTENANCE dir is [/mydir/test1]
```

I have changed line 4 of your script like this:

```
while getopts c:h:s:n:d: opt
```

It works fine for me under Cygwin, with `bash` version 4.1.10(4)-release.

Comment: +1 Same here. The only apparent problem in the original is the missing `:` *after* `d` in the option list.